# Threading with many function arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, python-multithreading

I have a function that takes multiple arguments (* args) of the string type. How every received argument is handled by a thread.
Here's how I handled it:

```py
def functionA(x):
    print(x)

def functionB(*args):
    for ar in args:
        th = threading.Thread(target=functionA, args=(ar, ))
        th.start()
```

But it doesn't work. Help me.

Comment: What you mean by *but it doesn't work* ? ... your code works fine.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Yes. but it runs synchronously (in turn), not at the same time

Comment: It's working ^^. I got confused when writing run () and strart ().Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments your code works fine, adding some delay to `functionA` shows that all threads are started at the time:

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime


def functionA(x, y):
    dte = datetime.utcnow()
    print(f"""Starting Thread {x:02} at: {dte:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}.{"{:03d}".format(dte.microsecond // 1000)}""")
    time.sleep(y)
    print(x)
    dte = datetime.utcnow()
    print(f"""Stopping Thread {x:02} at: {dte:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}.{"{:03d}".format(dte.microsecond // 1000)}""")

def functionB(*args):
    for i, ar in enumerate(args):
        th = threading.Thread(target=functionA, args=(ar, len(args)-i, ))
        th.start()


functionB(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Out:

```
Starting Thread 01 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.308
Starting Thread 02 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.308
Starting Thread 03 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.308
Starting Thread 04 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.308
Starting Thread 05 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
Starting Thread 06 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
Starting Thread 07 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
Starting Thread 08 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
Starting Thread 09 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
Starting Thread 10 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:43.309
10
Stopping Thread 10 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:44.310
9
Stopping Thread 09 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:45.311
8
Stopping Thread 08 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:46.309
7
Stopping Thread 07 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:47.314
6
Stopping Thread 06 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:48.311
5
Stopping Thread 05 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:49.310
4
Stopping Thread 04 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:50.310
3
Stopping Thread 03 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:51.311
2
Stopping Thread 02 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:52.309
1
Stopping Thread 01 at: 2020-11-22 15:01:53.311
```

Comment: It's working ^^. I got confused when writing run () and strart ().Thanks you